# Как передать данные resolve из ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

app.js

```js
'use strict'
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
    .constant('host', 'http://raport.local/public/')
    .factory('raports', ['$http', 'host', function ($http, host) {
        var raports = {};

        raports.getRaport = function (raportID) {
            return $http.get(host + 'raport/' + raportID);
        };

        return raports;
    }])
    .config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("raport", {
                url:"/raport/{raportID}",
                templateUrl: "tpl/raport.html",
                resolve: {
                    raporter: function ($stateParams,raports) {
                        return raports.getRaport($stateParams.raportID)
                            .$promise.then(
                            function(data) { return data; },
                            function(error) { return error; });
                    }
                },
                controller: "raportich"
            })
    }])
    .controller('raportich', ['raports','raporter', function (raports,raporter) {
        this.raportichca= raporter;
        //raports.getRaport(4);
    }]);

index.html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<a ui-sref="raport({raportID:4})">Ссылка</a>
<ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Сейчас, после загрузки страницы, не подключается шаблон из templateUrl, но проходит функция из resolve, а убрав resolve, подгружается шаблон. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, потому что у вас ошибка в функции `raporter`. Попробуйте переписать так `raporter: function ($stateParams,raports) {
                        return raports.getRaport($stateParams.raportID).then(
                            function(data) { return data; },
                            function(error) { return error; });
                    }`